# How do I use response from an API into the controller - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I tried to integrate an API that built-in laravel and now I have to use that API's response into the Codeigniter project, I'm developing a Codeigniter project(I'm not familiar with this framework and it's my first time working with this),

I finally could do it, I'm getting a response from an API

```
        $result = curl_exec($response); 
        $rs=json_decode($result,true); print_r($rs);
        return $rs;

        Array( 
             [user] => 
                  Array( 
                       [user_no] => PMRQ3fVd6eGEvd5aO9MDJg()() [name] => Anthony [middle_name] => S [lastname] => Mosteller [email] => AnthonyMosteller@test.net
              )
        )
```

and desperately trying to access the object full name, email, and user_no into my controller
But I am stuck now.

**controller code:**

```
$user=$this->userapi->userapicall($user_url,$token); 
$this->session->set_userdata('username',$user['name']); // here want to use full name (name+middle_name+lastname)
$this->session->set_userdata('useremail',$user['email']);
```

> I'm getting an error for name and email
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: name
>
> Filename: controllers/auth.php
>
> Line Number: 106

Do I need to create for each loop or seems something really silly mistake I make

I would appreciate an example of this.

Comment: Undefined index - meaning entry was not found in the array. Use print_r() or var_dump() to check your array($user)

Comment: as I see you array is [user => [user_no => .....]] So I suppose you need something like  $user['user']['name'] etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$rs = json_decode($result,true); print_r($rs);`

Here you are getting a multidimensional array. As per your code sample it looks like -

`$rs = ['user' =>  ['user_no' => 'PMRQ3fVd6eGEvd5aO9MDJg',  'name' => 'Anthony', 'middle_name' => 'S', 'lastname' => 'Mosteller', 'email' => 'AnthonyMosteller@test.net']];`

So if are trying to access user's name in controller -

```
$this->session->set_userdata('username',$user['user]['name']);
```

This should fix the problem.  Also you should check if you are getting success status from API.

Comment: Hi, it works for me but can you please explain or give a quick example of how should check if we are getting success status from API. - Thank you

Comment: Have a look at this gist. 

https://gist.github.com/mkerstner/12b67767468bffce6010b6986e531d5e

Comment: Thank you, it will be really helpful